# Constraint layout flow vertical align

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-flow

[image: UI to create]

I have the above UI to create and I am using flow to align the views

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/containerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/startGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="41dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/traySubTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:text="traySubTitle" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/presentedByIcon"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/amazon_logo"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/subTitleIconFlow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="traySubTitle,presentedByIcon"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trayTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:text="trayTitle" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/titleFlow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="trayTitle,subTitleIconFlow"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output I am getting is this

[image: Output]

How do I align tray title vertically using flow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code above to align the tray title vertically you have to add also the below constraint `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/titleFlow"` in the `subTitleIconFlow`. Also to get the above UI you have to change the order of `app:constraint_referenced_ids` in the `titleFlow` to `app:constraint_referenced_ids="subTitleIconFlow, trayTitle"`.

Below is the modified xml version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/startGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="41dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/traySubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:text="traySubTitle" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/presentedByIcon"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/amazon_logo"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/subTitleIconFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="traySubTitle,presentedByIcon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/titleFlow"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trayTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:text="trayTitle" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/titleFlow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="subTitleIconFlow, trayTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```